# How to pass the symbol & in @RequestParam?

Tags: java, spring, url, get, url-parameters

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/hello"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> getContent(@RequestParam(value = "url", required = true) String url) {
    System.out.println("My passed url is: " + url);
}
```

When I do

```
curl "localhost:8080/hello?url=http://www.test.com/boom/4?utm_source=Google+Places&utm_medium=LLM&utm_campaign=DAC+LLM"
```

The url I'm trying to pass as a GET parameter gets truncated at the `&` sign because it thinks it's the start of another GET parameter.

```
My passed url is http://www.test.com/boom/4?utm_source=Google+Places
```

Any way to get around this, or should I change from GET to POST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should encode your string in frontend for example using [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)